# Use in-Memory Data Table with OleDbDataAdaptor

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, oledbdataadapter

I have a DataTable that I create in memory...

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Columns.Add("My Col", string.Empty.GetType());
... add data ...
```

I would like to use this in an `OleDbDataAdapter` so I can run arbitrary SQL commands again it. How can I 'connect' the `OleDbDataAdapter` to the in-memory table?

Comment: One idea I have is to write to a csv file and re-read from there - but would prefer to avoid temp files if possible.

Comment: Why not of using LINQ?... Or I'm totally misunderstood the issue.

Comment: I am using data from a large variety of data sources and want a consistent interface for users to query the data (and queries are stored in text files). I need to use SQL here...

Comment: You could take a look on `Compute` method of `DataTable`, but probably it's not what you are really looking for.

Comment: And maybe [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/26b1f5f2-fb6f-4965-b20c-3d20a222d06c/how-we-can-use-sql-query-in-dataset-or-datatable?forum=Vsexpressvcs) thread could help you.